# Internal Error 500 in Openshift and Python without a traceback

Tags: python, git, openshift

I push a new part of code in Openshift for a specific page and since then, this page returns `Internal Error 500`.

I tried to run `rhc tail -a [appname]` but there isn't any error there, whereas in other situations I could saw the full traceback.

`[14/Jan/2015:06:44:31 -0500] "GET /healing HTTP/1.1" 500 291 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0"`

The page run without an error in local server. The git push didn't return any error and the status was success. Is there any way to have better access and see the traceback?

Comment: Have you tried ssh-ing to the gear and looking at the logs there? (~/app-root/logs) Also, you might try add logging to a file in your app to see where it breaks. To rule out HAProxy etc. try calling the failing URL from the gear itself (with curl f.i.)

Comment: Yes. I tried to access the logs in servers but there isn't something there.

Comment: Just to make sure: have you set `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in settings.py?